# List all the matched files starting from an index

Tags: zsh, wildcards

In zsh, there is the `[m,n]` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) which works as follows:

> [beg[,end]]
>
> specifies which of the matched filenames should be included in the
>   returned list. The syntax is the same as for array subscripts. beg and
>   the optional end may be mathematical expressions. As in parameter
>   subscripting they may be negative to make them count from the last
>   match backward. E.g.: ‘*(-OL[1,3])’ gives a list of the names of the
>   three largest files.

So for example, if I type:

```
print *([2,10])
```

it will return the elements 2 to 10 matched by `*`.

My question is: How can I ask zsh to return the matched elements starting from element X to the end of the list?

For example say I have 2500 files in one folder, BUT I don't know this number, and I would like to match all files **starting from** file 160.

I have tried:

1) `print -l *([160])`

-> only matches file # 160.

2) `print -l *([160,])`

-> No matches found

3) `print -l *~*([1,160])`

-> No matches found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative number counts from the end. The last element is -1.

```
print -l *([160,-1])
```

If you wanted the last 42:

```
print -l *([-42,-1])
```